# Why Service Bus link logs appeared?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

After some period of time I started to receive such logs. I didn't make any changes to log level. Moreover, it was a bit long time from when I updated Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package. Does anybody faced with such logs and also why it is happening? Thank you in advance.

Packages and version:

```
"Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.11.1"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.1"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0"
"Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.0"
.NET 7
```

[image]

Also used `AddAzureClients` which enables log forwarding.

Comment: There's not enough context available to answer the "why."   Showing your configuration and code would likely help.   As general information, these logs have long been emitted by the SB library and using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure` package to register with DI automatically starts the log forwarder.   More information is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging#logging-with-client-registration

Comment: What Jesse said. Details could lead to a very different answer based on what you do. For example, Isolated Worker Functions SDK requires a workaround. But a console app just a configuration.

Comment: @JesseSquire, yes it's seems to be an answer. I'm using my own package which wraps servicebusclient and it works fine. However, I started to use AddWebPubSubServiceClient, which is built in AddAzureClients. And as I understand it starts the log forwarder.

Comment: One of the way here to   Override : "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Warning" on that log level.  But it not seems nice.

Comment: These events are logged as "Verbose".   Filtering to "Warning" should exclude them.

Comment: Yeah, I rechecked and it excluded. However, is there any other options? Or this way is a good practice?

Comment: No, you cannot as Jesse shared that is the only option.

Comment: @MayankBargali There is another way, we stop use AddAzureClients, and inject necessary class directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of appearing of the logs was LogForwarder. I'm using in my solution **ServiceBus** and **WebPubSub**. The injection of **WebPubSub** was made with **AzureSdk** which uses LogForwarder. As I don't need **AzureSdk** I inject only **WebPubSubClient** and this ends such verbose logs.